# slick grid - unheck all rows for paging, sorting and search events

Tags: slickgrid

I am using SlickGrid with the checkbox selector plugin and the pagination plugin. I want to only allow the user to select rows for the current page. I noticed that slickgrid remembers values that the user selects on a previous page. Only when a user selects a row on the current page does it uncheck the rows on a previous page. Is it possible to uncheck all rows on a page change event.

Similarly if the user does a search I want to unselect all rows.

Same with sorting, unselect all rows for the grid when the user does a sort.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox selector plugin was not designed for pager. Whenever you set checkbox  as selected using the plugin, it remembers the row indices `_selectedRowsLookup` of the grid and re-apply the formatting when the grid invalidates. Thus, it will be the same rows check/unchecked on each page.

To achieve what you want, you have to customize the plugin where you need to:

1. Add a flag/field `isSelected` to your dataset that store if a record is selected
2. Set the formatter to check the `dataContext.isSelected` instead of using the `_selectedRowsLookup`
3. Change the `handleSelectedRowsChanged` to modify the field `isSelected` to true or false with the correct reference on the current page.
4. To select the rows of current page, change `handleHeaderClick` to only modify the rows displayed using the current `pagingInfo`
5. To clear the selection, reset the `isSelected` field to false and invalidate the grid rows.